# OpenMP task with and without parallel

Tags: task, openmp

```cpp
Node *head = &node1;
while (head)
{
    #pragma omp task 
        cout<<head->value<<endl;
    head = head->next;
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        Node *head = &node1;
        while (head)
        {
            #pragma omp task 
                cout<<head->value<<endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}
```

In the first block, I just created tasks without parallel directive, while in the second block, I used parallel directive and single directive which is a common way I saw in the papers.
I wonder what's the difference between them? BTW, I know the basic meaning of these directives.

The code in my comment:

```
void traverse(node *root)
{
    if (root->left) 
    {
        #pragma omp task 
        traverse(root->left);
    }
    if (root->right) 
    {
        #pragma omp task 
        traverse(root->right);
    }
    process(root);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that in the first block you are *not* really creating any tasks since the block itself is not nested (neither syntactically nor lexically) inside an active parallel region. In the second block the `task` construct is syntactically nested inside the `parallel` region and would queue explicit tasks if the region happens to be active at run-time (an active parallel region is one that executes with a team of more than one thread). Lexical nesting is less obvious. Observe the following example:

```c
void foo(void)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      #pragma omp task
      bar();
}

int main(void)
{
   foo();

   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
   {
      #pragma omp single
      foo();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The first call to `foo()` happens outside of any parallel regions. Hence the `task` directive does (almost) nothing and all calls to `bar()` happen serially. The second call to `foo()` comes from inside the parallel region and hence new tasks would be generated inside `foo()`. The `parallel` region is active since the number of threads was fixed to `4` by the `num_threads(4)` clause.

This different behaviour of the OpenMP directives is a design feature. The main idea is to be able to write code that could execute both as serial and as parallel.

Still the presence of the `task` construct in `foo()` does some code transformation, e.g. `foo()` is transformed to something like:

```c
void foo_omp_fn_1(void *omp_data)
{
   bar();
}

void foo(void)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      OMP_make_task(foo_omp_fn_1, NULL);
}
```

Here `OMP_make_task()` is a hypothetical (not publicly available) function from the OpenMP support library that queues a call to the function, supplied as its first argument. If `OMP_make_task()` detects, that it works outside an active parallel region, it would simply call `foo_omp_fn_1()` instead. This adds some overhead to the call to `bar()` in the serial case. Instead of `main -> foo -> bar`, the call goes like `main -> foo -> OMP_make_task -> foo_omp_fn_1 -> bar`. The implication of this is slower serial code execution.

This is even more obviously illustrated with the worksharing directive:

```c
void foo(void)
{
   int i;

   #pragma omp for
   for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      bar();
}

int main(void)
{
   foo();

   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
   {
      foo();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The first call to `foo()` would run the loop in serial. The second call would distribute the 12 iterations among the 4 threads, i.e. each thread would only execute 3 iteratons. Once again, some code transformation magic is used to achieve this and the serial loop would run slower than if no `#pragma omp for` was present in `foo()`.

The lesson here is to never add OpenMP constructs where they are not really necessary.

Comment: It seems that I made a mistake in the usage of task. This problem arose because I saw a code of recursively traversing the tree with only "task" as I added in the question. I guess that there should be "parallel" and "single" enclosing the traverse function where it is called. Many thanks to your sincere answer.

Comment: @AnnieKim, yes, the `traverse()` function as shown in your question would traverse the tree in parallel if called from within an active `parallel` region and serially otherwise. That's the beauty of OpenMP :) (despite the added overhead)